# Why is Yesod.Request.FileInfo (fileContentType) a Text?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am just starting out with Haskell and Yesod so please forgive if I am missing something obvious.

I am noticing that fileContentType in [Yesod.Request](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/0.9.4.1/doc/html/Yesod-Request.html).FileInfo is a Text even though [Yesod.Content](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/0.9.4.1/doc/html/Yesod-Content.html#t%3aContentType) has an explicit ContentType.  I'm wondering, why is it not a ContentType instead and what is the cleanest conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to a larger issue. A lot of the HTTP spec is stated in terms of ASCII. The question is, how do we represent it. There are essentially three choices:

1. Create a special newtype `Ascii` around a `ByteString`. This is the most correct, but also very tedious since it involves a lot of wrapping/unwrapping. We tried this approach, and got a lot of negative feedback.
2. Use normal `ByteString`s. This is efficient, and mostly correct, but allows people to enter non-ASCII binary data.
3. Use `Text` (or `String`). This is the most developer-friendly, but allows you to enter non-ASCII character data. It's a bit less efficient than (1) or (2) due to the encoding/decoding overhead.

Overall, we've been moving towards (3) for most operations, especially for things like sessions keys which are internal to Yesod. You could say that `ContentType` is an inconsistency and should be changed to `Text`, but I think it doesn't seem to bother anyone, is a bit more semantic, and a bit faster.

tl;dr: No good reason :)

Comment: Ha! Well, good to know. Thanks for the explanation. I come from the Java world where current best practices would dictate 4. MIME-specific wrapper type for the sake of strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the type of `Content` with the type of `ContentType`.  The `fileContent` field of `FileInfo` should be `ContentType` - and it is, modulo the type alias - the type of `fileContentType` is `Text` which would be `ContentTypeType`.  It might help to imaging the last world as a prefixing adjective, so `ContentType` == the type of `Content`.

Comment: As I understand it: ContentType is an alias for String, representing the mime type (e.g. "text/html") of the Content; fileContentType is a Text representing the mime type of the fileContent; 
fileContent is a ByteString representing the Content of the file.

Comment: Well then perhaps I confused it - Michael implies as much in his authoritative answer.